# SQL Server : delay trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers, database-trigger

I have customer machine what inserts data into my SQL Server database at midnight. In SQL Server there is trigger to delete old records upon insert.

The problem is, the customer does bunch of single insert commands (instead of using bulk insert), actually hundreds of them. I cannot control that. What I did is to record last trigger time and if datediff is less than one hour, don't do anything. I read using `WAITFOR` in triggers is a bad idea as it locks the table until trigger execution is done. Is there any other way? Cheers.

```
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF DATEDIFF(HOUR, (SELECT TOP 1 TimeStamp 
                       FROM HouseKeepingStats 
                       ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC), GETDATE()) > 1 
    BEGIN
        EXEC HouseKeeping;
    END
END
```

Comment: "Is there any other way"? Probably. But discussion of alternatives starts with a discussion of your goal, not the chosen path that does not work. So - what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Cheers @SMor, what I'm trying to do is to clear old records upon insert but because db server get flooded with insert query trigger at the first one is not helping especially the purpose of it is to remove old rows. It would be 'nice' to trigger at the last insert or ever few minutes after. I'm trying to accomplish it within SQL server.

Comment: It seems to me the trigger isn't the right place for housekeeping. A separate scheduled batch job would be more appropriate.

Comment: You can use SQL Server Agent to schedule T-SQL batch

Comment: Eh, just found the Agent is not working and it will not start (Error 1067). On the other hand, I thought, if I trigger on insert/update then it will only perform it when (after) a new data inserted.

Comment: If the agent isn't working, then you should check it out and fix it.  Whether the service wasn't registered correctly, or the user with which its running doesn't have the appropriate permissions.  Using a trigger on a table for history cleanup will cause performance issues.  Not to mention it could result in a table-lock, should there be a large amount of data to remove.  As Dan and Dmitry said, the best way is to create a scheduled cleanup process.

Comment: Cheers guys, I'll go now to battle the SQL Agent service. The problem is the machine is remote and I have **very** limited access to it without causing major panic (when I access VNC lol)